# Nginx Redirect Subdomain with SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx, subdomain

So I've got this port 80 redirect working fine

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name "~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.site-box\.it$";
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$subdomain.sitebox.co permanent;
}
```

But I want https to work too, because some old links are left around that have `https://guy.site-box.it`

But this doesn't work

```
server {
    listen  443;
    server_name "~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.site-box\.it$";
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$subdomain.sitebox.co permanent;
}
```

It seems to cause nothing in the Nginx conf file to work.  I just get cloudflare errors on the main site, and on the testing guy.site-box.it it just says page is not available.

Any idea how to get the SSL subdomain to work?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need 2 certificates: for `subdomain.site-box.it` and for `subdomain.sitebox.co`. If you have wildcard certificate - good, can use one server block. If you have separate certificate - need to create one `server` for each subdomain (because certificate paths are different).

Also, you need openssl with [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) support (well, almost all modern version has) and check browser/os support. SNI - it's for https name-based hosting.

Also, [better](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls) use `return 301` instead of `rewrite`. `return 301 https://$subdomain.sitebox.co` much better.

And finally you `server` block not configured well. You forgot `ssl` keyword and certificate paths.

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 ssl_certificate ... ;
 ssl_certificate_key ... ;
}
```

Comment: I don't have or want a cert for site-box.it. I used to have it there, but we changed domains to sitebox.co which has a wildcard domain.  But there are old links to https://site-box.it still.

Comment: Adding the ssl keyword didn't seem to help the nginx failure either.

Comment: Do you still have active certificates for site-box.it and all subdomains? If you have, but expired, browser will warn.

Comment: I no longer have a valid wildcard cert for *.site-box.it. But that's why I want the redirect to work, because I do have a valid wildcard for *.sitebox.co

Comment: Any location/rewrite rules processed after SSL handshake. So, you need valid certificates. You can try to use old, but browser will be blablabla about it.

Comment: So the only way to redirect old https URLs is to pay a cert I'm not going to use?  That seems like it's not right.

Comment: SSL target is to protect http channel. Redirects - it's HTTP ability. So, SSL before HTTP. You can buy cheap certificate or even free (startssl.com for example - wildcard not free, but you can create separate certificates per subdomain).

Comment: So basically, changing the domain screwed us over? Can I redirect the old domain on a DNS level? Maybe just make a domain forward from the domain registrar?

Comment: Nop :( If you will find domain registar who allow "redirect domains" - it's 100% combination of DNS and HTTP server.